# Cairooverlay in Gstreamer1.0/Python 3

Tags: python, video, gstreamer, cairo, gobject

I'm trying to use cairooverlay with Gstreamer 1.0 and python 3.

I started trying to traslate [this example](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-good/tree/tests/examples/cairo/cairo_overlay.c) in python. So far i've managed to obtain [this code](http://pastebin.com/CQ2N5y2S) where the pipeline works and the cairooverlay "draw" callback is called. The problem now is how to write stuff on it. The second argument is a misterious "CairoContext" with no method at all, so i'm at loss.

Comment: Apparently the CairoContext here is actually gi.repository.cairo.Context

Comment: You should import cairo module to; the function from there do apply to your context, only not shown because of dinamic binding. Do a fast check: ctx.set_source_rgba(1.0,.0,.0,1.0);ctx.line_to(100,100);ctx.stroke() ps:check the spell of function call, i'm writing from memory (where ctx is your context)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem as a bug in cairooverlay gobject binding.

The bug is described [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=694604) and a workaround is provided [here](https://bug694604.bugzilla-attachments.gnome.org/attachment.cgi?id=237351)

Comment: I had a slightly different issue, in that Fedora doesn't package the libgstcairo.so (the underlying module) for the cairooverlay.  See details at the [Bug Tracker](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1048513).